# plugin is not defined in instance.vue

Tags: vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

I struggle to add a plugin in Nuxt.js. I have been looking to the doc and all kind of similar problems, but I got the same error: `simpleParallax is not defined`.

I tried different approach on all files

`nuxt.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [
     {src: '~/plugins/simple-parallax.js', mode:'client', ssr: false} 
],
```

`plugins/simple-parallax.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import simpleParallax from 'simple-parallax-js';
Vue.use(new simpleParallax);
```

`index.vue`:

```js
Export default {

     plugins: ['@/plugins/simple-parallax.js'],
     mounted() {
        var image = document.getElementsByClassName('hero');
        new simpleParallax(image, {
            scale: 1.8
        });
    }
}
```

Error message:

> ReferenceError: simpleParallax is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I found out so far is to register `simpleParallax` on the Vue `prototype` like so in a plugin nuxt file with the name `simple-parallax.client.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import simpleParallax from 'simple-parallax-js';
Vue.prototype.$simpleParallax = simpleParallax;
```

Also my `nuxt.config.js` file if anyone would like to verify that as well:

```js
plugins: [
  {src: '~/plugins/simple-parallax.client.js', mode: 'client', ssr: false}
],
```

I then have access to the plugin before instantiation in my case in the `mounted` life cycle of the primary or root component to grab the desired HTML elements and instantiate their individual parallax with the newly added global method `this.$simpleParallax`

For example I can then intiate a certain HTML element to have its parallax like so:

```js
const someHTMLElement = document.querySelectorAll('.my-html-element');
const options = {...} // your desired parallax options
new this.$simpleParallax(someHTMLElement, options);
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't need to use plugin here.
Just `import simpleParallax from 'simple-parallax-js'` in your component and init it with your image in `mounted` hook.

`index.vue`:

```js
import simpleParallax from 'simple-parallax-js'

export default {
  ...
  mounted() {
    // make sure this runs on client-side only
    if (process.client) {
      var image = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')
      new simpleParallax(image)
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

And don't forget to remove previously created plugin, it's redundant here.

Comment: Thank you, but when i do this i get " window is not defined from the plugin itself"...:/

Comment: @KelligJourdren, Oh, sure, I forget about SSR. I have updated the answer :)

Comment: @KelligJourdren so how did you solve this issue, did you register it as a plugin or did something else?